# Change the position of blue highlight on select box dropdown

Tags: css

I was trying to change the highlight/focus (not sure which it actually refers) background position color when user moves the mouse over the select drop-down list. The blue background box is coming a little below the text. I want to move its position a little bit. What type of css property it needs to add. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Is it an OS dropdown or JS one ?

Can you share us code as snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give padding top to every list item of dropdown menu, a